# Is it possible to forward emails addressed to @a.com, to @b.com without a mail server on a.com

Tags: email, dns

I have two websites, we'll call them a.com and b.com.  I already have a mail server running on b.com.  What I would like to do is have any email sent to @a.com to be automatically forwarded to b.com.  I edited the only MX record in the a.com DNS settings to be...

```
Priority: 10
Host: @
Points To: b.com
```

After setting this up and giving it time to propagate, mail sent to a.com does not go through and I get a "Message not delivered" response from my email client.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MX-Record does only tell the webserver where to deliver mail for that specific domain. So any mail sent to `user@a.com` will be sent to the mailserver at `b.com`, that does not mean that they get forwarded to `user@b.com`. You will have to configure your mailserver at `b.com` to accept mails for the `a.com` domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I do have the server at b.com set up to catch all emails without a username and put them in one inbox, but the test emails I sent never showed up there.  Is it possible that it is only configured to receive emails to @b.com, and therefore rejecting them?  I can't test this until tomorrow unfortunately, but I will dig around in the settings and see if I find anything.

Comment: @StapleGun: Correct; the mailserver on `b.com` will reject emails that aren't addressed to destinations on a domain it's expecting to handle mail for.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff, sounds like this is the problem.  I will follow up tomorrow after trying the changes.